# Do military pilots use amphetamines or other stimulants?

Tags: military

Related to this question: [Do military pilots have flight & rest hours regulation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8784/do-military-pilots-have-flight-rest-hours-regulation)

According to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_and_culture_of_substituted_amphetamines#Military_use), amphetamines were commonly given to Allied pilots.

Are they still in use today?

Comment: I would guess they are, but nobody really wants to talk about it. They were certainly used a lot in WWII, to the point that German pilots showed symptoms of overdosing with Pervitin (colloquially called "Kanalkoller").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The U.S. Air Force (and Navy) still uses, and has used off and on since WWII,  what are commonly referred to as "Go Pills" for instances when pilots need to be up for long periods of time - in wartime, sometimes longer than the crew rest regulation. (These pills can also be used for altering sleep cycles, along with "no-go" pills; for example, when changing from day to night).

The most common go pill is [Dexedrine](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextroamphetamine), which is an amphetamine. You can find some more information in [this article](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/3071789/ns/us_news-only/t/go-pills-war-drugs/).

Comment: When I deployed to Korea for the first time, I did the flight surgeon test of the go and no go pills.  I really didn't notice much of an effect from either.  But yes, SSumner is 100% correct.

Comment: I've tested the no-go pills, and they had minimal to no effect on me, but one of the others in my squadron told me the tested ones are low dosage and only to test for allergic/adverse reactions. The real things are stronger.

Comment: I would like to add that these 'go-pills' are nothing more than Adderall! (Dextroamphetamine!) (In other words nothing more than the average ADHD student such as myself takes. Ironically, I take Adderall and thus am not allowed to enter the military because of it.

Comment: That is quite ironic considering that my prescribed Adderall would prevent me from passing an FAA medical and getting a PPL.