# Is air to air refuelling possible at "cruising altitude"?

Tags: altitude, mid-air-refueling

When an aircraft uses air to air refuelling are there constraints on the maximum altitude this can take place at?

For instance I'm guessing that a Boeing Globemaster when on a long journey would cruise at 8,000m or higher ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-17_Globemaster_III) says service ceiling is 14,000m / 45,000'). Is there any reason why air-to-air refuelling can't take place at that sort of height?

I'm wondering whether there's something about the lack of air pressure that makes it problematic to transfer fuel or the speeds that must be used for the transfer are not viable at very high altitudes.

Answer (score 25):

The main limitation is that the receiver needs to have enough excess thrust available to be able to precisely maintain formation on the tanker. Near the service ceiling, you typically don't have a lot of excess thrust, so refueling happens somewhat lower than that.  Since fighter generally have more excess thrust at a given altitude than a transport will, they can refuel at somewhat higher altitudes.

Other than wanting to have enough excess thrust available to accelerate forward in the event of a "breakaway" call, tankers don't have particular limitations *that I'm aware of*, though I've not flown those. (I'd assume being right at the limits of IAS / TAS isn't particularly comfortable for a tanker, so at least something below their service ceiling, but I don't know what that limit is.)

Pumps, rather than differential pressure, move the fuel, so that system is unlikely to drive any altitude constraints.

It's common to hear refueling happening in the mid-20's over the U.S.  How much that's driven by airspace availability vs by performance, I don't know.

Comment: Totally ignorant on this but wouldn't an aircraft be easier to control in denser air? This manoeuvre seems involve some precision flying and I would expect ease of control to be an issue.

Comment: @RoyC: Thicker air would give you more control authority for the same deflection of a control surface at the same true airspeed, but IDK if that makes precision formation stuff easier.  You want to make really *small* adjustments to angle to guide the plane onto the refuelling tether; if it takes larger actual control inputs from your hand to do that, it might actually help.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Makes sense, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @RoyC: According to [@Efe's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83054/is-air-to-air-refuelling-possible-at-cruising-altitude/83062#83062), high altitude refueling would often mean lower *indicated* airspeed, so the small planes actually are more sluggish.  So my assumption of near-constant IAS with altitude apparently wasn't right, and it makes sense that having the plane seem to respond more slowly to control inputs would make things harder for the pilot.  Maybe my guess about making larger control inputs isn't how it works.

Answer (score 19):

From the [NATO website](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/news_134405.htm) describing the a330mrtt:

> The Airbus tankers will be able to refuel a wide range of aircraft
> such as NATO AWACS surveillance planes; F-35, F-16 and Rafale fighter
> aircraft; and C-17 transport planes. Refueling can be performed at an
> altitude up to 35,000 ft while cruising at speeds between 180 knots
> and 325 knots.

[image]

The A330mrtt has a [service ceiling of 42,700ft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330_MRTT) so refueling is constrained to occur below the maximum cruising altitude of the tanker, but not by much.

The service ceilings for the F35, F16 and Rafale are all above 50kft, so fighters are not the constraint. The AWACS service ceiling is 35kft, while the C17 goes to 45kft. The website did not disclose whether each class of aircraft had a different limit.

Fuel is transferred by pump and is independent of speed or altitude.

In response to comments:

The MRTT designation stands for Multi Role Tanker Transport; intended for uses in addition to tankering. It is based on the A330-200 but uses the A340 wing which has reinforcing for two outer engines, which are swapped out for Cobham fuel delivery pods. Standard passenger and cargo decks cover the transport part of the designation; tankering fuel is only carried in the wings unlike the KC10 which also has aux tanks in the cargo hold.

Comment: Why does it have windows? Isn't that where the fuel goes?

Comment: @DanSheppard dollars to doughnuts it’s a commercial variant, and removing the windows costs *more* not less. If you want a real answer, ask a real question :)

Comment: Some (if not most) tankers are recycled commercial aircraft and don’t even have special fuel tanks, they just use the standard tanks.  Given that an airliner carries enough fuel for a flight of several thousand miles, it’s plenty to keep a few small planes supplied.

Comment: @DanSheppard Tankers often are also used for troop/supply transport. The passenger deck is still available. See this related answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15091/how-is-fuel-stored-in-a-tanker-aircraft

Comment: @DanSheppard the RAF A330MRTTs are operated by AirTanker, which uses them for passenger transport when they aren't being used by the military. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirTanker_Services

Comment: I'm now wondering what the inside looks like. I'd kind of imagined they were like road tankers with a cylinder of fuel making part of the body. (I know nothing about these things!) I guess it's not like that, then.

Comment: @DanSheppard, I've been inside a couple (KC-135 and KC-10) at airshows.  The tankage is basically the bottom third to bottom half of the fuselage; the upper part can be used for cargo (self-loading or otherwise).

Comment: @DanSheppard the inside of an MRTT looks the same as a regular airliner as the fuel they give away is contained inside the standard tanks. Since they don’t take pax or freight during refuelling missions they can just fill it up with gas to give away rather than balancing fuel / freight. Indeed the UK VIP jet for the Prime Minister is a refueller jet with a modded interior and fancier paintwork. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44eC4XETigQ

Answer (score 12):

Airliner-type aircraft fly close to stall speed at cruise altitude as their maximum speed in terms of Mach (Mmo) and their stall speed are within 15-20 knots to each other. Tankers cannot fly any faster (excluding buddy tanking, which generally happens at much lower altitudes and in the vicinity of the carrier), so fighters are also constrained to fly close to their stall speed to stay with the tanker. Fighters (well all aircraft actually) are sluggish to maneuver at that speed and this makes refueling more difficult. Furthermore, the weight added to the receiver during refueling more strongly affects the behavior of the receiver at low airspeeds.

For this reason, refueling is normally done at lower altitudes, to enable the tanker to fly at higher indicated airspeeds to keep the receiver aircraft further away from stall.

The SR-71 used to refuel very close to its stall speed, while the KC-135Q tanker flew at Vmo at an altitude where Mmo was not a problem. Despite this, to stay with the tanker and not stall, the SR-71 had to light one afterburner when its tanks were close to full and refueled with a sideslip.

Comment: At cruise, an airliner may have 15-20 knots between MMO & the low speed **buffet** limit, but that low speed buffet is *significantly* above the actual **stall** speed.

Comment: True, what I meant is that the tanker has only 15-20 knots to play with. The fact that a tanker won't actually stall doesn't mean that they'll fly it in the buffetting region to help a slow receiver airplane catch up.

Comment: If they fly on the buffet wouldn’t that make it turbulent for the receiver?

Comment: As long as they've wiped the buffet clean... sorry that was too easy. I don't believe so, the receiver would be further below the tanker's wings so it would most likely be away from wingwash.

Comment: When I was in a KC-130 Squadron we refueled CH-53 helicopters and F-4 Phantoms.  (Not at the same time!)  I was in the back so I didn't pay attention to the airspeeds, but obviously they were quite different...

Comment: Exactly. That's why the KC-130 flew below economic cruise altitude, to fly slow enough for the Stallion and fast enough for the Phantom. This leeway is impossible at cruise altitude.
Also, I believe the KC-130 had the ramp open during refuelings, doesn't that by itself rule out refueling above 13000 feet?

Comment: No, ramp open was definitely not SOP.  Possible, and makes for cool photos, but doors were closed and we flew high and fast while refueling jets.

Answer (score 9):

Some of the answers have hinted at a bit of a problem in the question, but I think it's worth bringing it out a little more clearly: *whose* cruising altitude do you care about?

When a KC-135Q is refueling an SR-71, it's flying what for it is high and fast--but for the SR-71 is fairly low and slow.

When a (non-Q) KC-135 is refueling an A10, we get pretty much the opposite situation. The A10 is flying high and fast (for an A10)--but the 135 if flying low and really slow (as in: drop not only the flaps, but also the landing gear to add drag).

As others have also alluded, you do need more maneuvering than just normal flying so as a starting point, take the aircraft with the lower cruising altitude, and subtract something like 20% for a starting point on a reasonable altitude for refueling.

Comment: Great point Jerry, same for C-130s. Especially as the performance gets worse the more fuel you onload! :)