# What is the longest range unrefueled production aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance, range

I was looking at the [re-engined B52 project](https://www.airandspaceforces.com/rolls-royce-wins-b-52-re-engining-program-worth-2-6-billion/) which was supposed to extend its [8800sm unrefueled combat range/10,145sm ferry range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) by 40%, making it 12,320/14,203sm.

What is the longest range unrefueled production aircraft? Is this it? No ferry tanks or one off stcs allowed. Legitimate programs not yet in production are ok, meaning funded or otherwise substantiated.

Comment: My offer on the table: "*In 2019, Qantas flew one of its A380s back to base in Sydney from Dresden, Germany, after refurbishment. The plane was empty and flew for over 18 hours and about 10,000 miles.*" ([source](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/airbus-a380-superjumbo-astonishing-facts/index.html))

Comment: @sophit The [Airbus Aircraft Characteristics](https://www.airbus.com/en/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics) for the A380 show a ferry range of about 9600 NM (without wind), so significantly less than the ~12300 NM claimed by the B52.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought only production aircraft counted. Anyway nice to know 

Comment: @sophit Only production counts, but it doesn't have to be currently in production. It also doesn't have to be commercial.

Comment: Do military tanker aircraft have the ability to use all the fuel onboard for their own engines? If so then I would expect such an aircraft to win the range comparision.

Comment: Does the Space Shuttle count?

Comment: @DaveGremlin: It didn't even need fuel to absolutely obliterate the record!

Comment: @PeterGreen Tankers usually distribute their own fuel from their regular fuel tanks. See [Do tanker aircraft distribute their own fuel?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/do-tanker-aircraft-distribute-their-own-fuel)

Comment: @DaveGremlin Clever thought, but I would put drop tanks in the same category as ferry tanks and the shuttle external tank is one giant drop tank.

Comment: In theory, any sailplane can beat everything above. 

Comment: And there’s not much point in making an aircraft with a range greater than 10,800 nautical miles, as it can reach any point on the Earth on a single flight.